# Are there any versions of ModSecurity that work well with supported versions of Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, mod-security

I'm trying to build Nginx and ModSecurity together in order to use the [OWASP- Core Rule Set Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project).

According to the modsecurity download page, the latest version of modsecurity (2.9.1) is not currently stable when used with nginx.  This is consistent with my experience (not working properly on either Nginx 1.8.x or 1.9.x).  I've also tried the `nginx_refactoring` branch of ModSecurity, but that's non-functional too, and hasn't seen a commit in nearly 2 years anyway.

I know there is a new version of modsecurity coming up (libmodsecurity), but that isn't ready yet.

Is there any combination of ModSecurity and a supported version of Nginx that is known to be working?

Answer (score 0):

Now is working, basically you need:

- Compile ModSecurity Branch  v3/master (necessary because you need the common core
  libmodsecurity)
- Compile ModSecurity-nginx connector
- Compile nginx  with add-module ModSecurity-nginx
- Clone and configure  OWASP ruleset and config to Nginx

This would work

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/nginx-with-libmodsecurity-and-owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set-on-ubuntu-1604/